# Add a score in a simple math game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just learning Javascript and this is one of my first exercises. I'm trying to do a simple math game for my daughter and in general terms, it works. You can have a "good" or "try again" result but the only way that I found for having a new question was by reloading the page.

I would like to include a score and get new values every time you have a right answer, I tried by adding this into a function or a for, but it didn't work.

Can you help me with some ideas? Or any general recommendation will be great. Thanks!

```js
var mal = 0;
var bien = 0;



//variables divs
var divsumando1 = document.getElementById("divsumando1");
var divsumando2 = document.getElementById("divsumando2");
var btnopcion1 = document.getElementById("btnopcion1");
var btnopcion2 = document.getElementById("btnopcion2");
var btnopcion3 = document.getElementById("btnopcion3");
var retro = document.getElementById("retro");
var imagen = document.getElementById("img");
var buenas = document.getElementById("buenas");
var malas = document.getElementById("malas");
malas.innerHTML=mal;
buenas.innerHTML=bien;





//variables sumas

var sumando1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var sumando2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var error1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
var error2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
var sorteo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
var correcto = sumando1 + sumando2;
var incorrecto1 = correcto + error1;
var incorrecto2 = correcto - error2;
var resultados = new Array (correcto,incorrecto1,incorrecto2);




//sumandos
divsumando1.innerHTML = sumando1;
divsumando2.innerHTML = sumando2;


//acomodo resultados
if (sorteo == 0){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[0];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
}
if (sorteo == 1){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[0];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
}
if (sorteo == 2){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[2];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[0];
}


  
//funciones botones
function btn1(){
  if (btnopcion1.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn2(){
  if (btnopcion2.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn3(){
  if (btnopcion3.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
```

```css
root {
  --color-bg: #FFF;
  --color-text-main: #000000;
  --color-primary: #FFFF00;
  --wrapper-height: 87vh;
  --image-max-width: 300px;
  --image-margin: 3rem;
  --font-family: "HK Grotesk";
  --font-family-header: "HK Grotesk";
}

/* Basic page style resets */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Import fonts */
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Regular.otf?v=1603136326027")
    format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Bold.otf?v=1603136323437")
    format("opentype");
}

/* Our remix on glitch button */
.btn--remix {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 2.75rem;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.btn--remix img {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.btn--remix:hover {
  background-color: #D0FFF1;
}

/* Navigation grid */
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
  padding: 1rem 0 0.75rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

.footer a:not(.btn--remix):link,
a:not(.btn--remix):visited {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: none;
}
.footer a:hover {
  background: var(--color-primary);
}

.footer .links {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.divider {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
/******************************************************************************
END Glitch hello-app default styles
******************************************************************************/

body {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

/* Page structure */
.wrapper {
  min-height: var(--wrapper-height);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.title {
  color: #2800FF;
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 105%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.illustration {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: var(--image-max-width);
  margin-top: var(--image-margin);
}

.button{
  font-size:35px;
  background-color:#ff4567;
  border-radius:50px;
  border:none;
  padding:20px 30px;
  color:#fff;
  margin:0px 10px;
}

.text{
  font-size:70px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
}

.text-retro{
  font-size:45px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sumas!</title>
  
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- the wrapper and content divs set margins and positioning -->
    <div id="score" style="text-align:center; padding:30px 0px;">
    <span>Good</span><span id="buenas"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>Wrong</span><span id="malas"></span> 
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span id="divsumando1" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">+</span>
    <span id="divsumando2" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">=</span>
    </div>
      
      
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="btnopcion1" onclick="btn1()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion2" onclick="btn2()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion3" onclick="btn3()" class="button"></button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="retro" class="text-retro">  
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="img" src="" height="200" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of refreshing the page just call the randomizer function and update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var mal = 0;
var bien = 0;

//variables divs
var divsumando1 = document.getElementById("divsumando1");
var divsumando2 = document.getElementById("divsumando2");
var btnopcion1 = document.getElementById("btnopcion1");
var btnopcion2 = document.getElementById("btnopcion2");
var btnopcion3 = document.getElementById("btnopcion3");
var retro = document.getElementById("retro");
var imagen = document.getElementById("img");
var buenas = document.getElementById("buenas");
var malas = document.getElementById("malas");
malas.innerHTML=mal;
buenas.innerHTML=bien;

var sumando1, sumando2, error1, error2, sorteo, correcto, incorrecto1, incorrecto2, resultados;

//variables sumas
function generate () {
retro.innerHTML="";
retro.style.color="";
imagen.src="";

sumando1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
sumando2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
error1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
error2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
sorteo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
correcto = sumando1 + sumando2;
incorrecto1 = correcto + error1;
incorrecto2 = correcto - error2;
resultados = new Array (correcto,incorrecto1,incorrecto2);

//sumandos
divsumando1.innerHTML = sumando1;
divsumando2.innerHTML = sumando2;


//acomodo resultados
if (sorteo == 0){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[0];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
}
if (sorteo == 1){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[0];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
}
if (sorteo == 2){
  btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[2];
  btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
  btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[0];
}
}
  
//funciones botones
function btn1(){
  if (btnopcion1.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn2(){
  if (btnopcion2.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn3(){
  if (btnopcion3.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    setTimeout(function() {
      generate();
    }, 2000);
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML= mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}

generate();
```

```css
root {
  --color-bg: #FFF;
  --color-text-main: #000000;
  --color-primary: #FFFF00;
  --wrapper-height: 87vh;
  --image-max-width: 300px;
  --image-margin: 3rem;
  --font-family: "HK Grotesk";
  --font-family-header: "HK Grotesk";
}

/* Basic page style resets */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Import fonts */
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Regular.otf?v=1603136326027")
    format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Bold.otf?v=1603136323437")
    format("opentype");
}

/* Our remix on glitch button */
.btn--remix {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 2.75rem;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.btn--remix img {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.btn--remix:hover {
  background-color: #D0FFF1;
}

/* Navigation grid */
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
  padding: 1rem 0 0.75rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

.footer a:not(.btn--remix):link,
a:not(.btn--remix):visited {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: none;
}
.footer a:hover {
  background: var(--color-primary);
}

.footer .links {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.divider {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
/******************************************************************************
END Glitch hello-app default styles
******************************************************************************/

body {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

/* Page structure */
.wrapper {
  min-height: var(--wrapper-height);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.title {
  color: #2800FF;
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 105%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.illustration {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: var(--image-max-width);
  margin-top: var(--image-margin);
}

.button{
  font-size:35px;
  background-color:#ff4567;
  border-radius:50px;
  border:none;
  padding:20px 30px;
  color:#fff;
  margin:0px 10px;
}

.text{
  font-size:70px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
}

.text-retro{
  font-size:45px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="score" style="text-align:center; padding:30px 0px;">
    <span>Good</span><span id="buenas"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>Wrong</span><span id="malas"></span> 
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span id="divsumando1" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">+</span>
    <span id="divsumando2" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">=</span>
    </div>
      
      
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="btnopcion1" onclick="btn1()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion2" onclick="btn2()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion3" onclick="btn3()" class="button"></button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="retro" class="text-retro">  
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="img" src="" height="200" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given just the approach this code will work in your case. But this code can be optimized way better. I hope you can do it on your own.

```js
var mal = 0;
var bien = 0;



  //variables divs
  var divsumando1 = document.getElementById("divsumando1");
  var divsumando2 = document.getElementById("divsumando2");
  var btnopcion1 = document.getElementById("btnopcion1");
  var btnopcion2 = document.getElementById("btnopcion2");
  var btnopcion3 = document.getElementById("btnopcion3");
  var retro = document.getElementById("retro");
  var imagen = document.getElementById("img");
  var buenas = document.getElementById("buenas");
  var malas = document.getElementById("malas");
  malas.innerHTML=mal;
  buenas.innerHTML=bien;

var correcto,incorrecto1,incorrecto2,resultados;
function randomize () {
  
  //variables sumas

  var sumando1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var sumando2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var error1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  var error2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  var sorteo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
   correcto = sumando1 + sumando2;
   incorrecto1 = correcto + error1;
   incorrecto2 = correcto - error2;
   resultados = new Array (correcto,incorrecto1,incorrecto2);




  //sumandos
  divsumando1.innerHTML = sumando1;
  divsumando2.innerHTML = sumando2;


  //acomodo resultados
  if (sorteo == 0){
    btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[0];
    btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
    btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
  }
  if (sorteo == 1){
    btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[1];
    btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[0];
    btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[2];
  }
  if (sorteo == 2){
    btnopcion1.innerHTML = resultados[2];
    btnopcion2.innerHTML = resultados[1];
    btnopcion3.innerHTML = resultados[0];
  }

}

  
//funciones botones
function btn1(){
  if (btnopcion1.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      randomize();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn2(){
  if (btnopcion2.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      randomize();
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}
function btn3(){
  if (btnopcion3.innerText == correcto){
    retro.innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    setTimeout(function() {
      randomize();;
    }, 2000);
    bien = bien+1;
    buenas.innerHTML=bien;
    retro.style.color = "#00c284";
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fclap.gif?v=1619362844724"
  } else {
    retro.innerHTML = "revisa tu <br /> respuesta";
    retro.style.color = "#ff4567";
    mal = mal+1;
    malas.innerHTML=mal;
    imagen.src="https://cdn.glitch.com/a1593aec-03c8-4f6f-a2ff-db63d05e4fb9%2Fno.gif?v=1619364940903";
  }
}

randomize();
```

```css
root {
  --color-bg: #FFF;
  --color-text-main: #000000;
  --color-primary: #FFFF00;
  --wrapper-height: 87vh;
  --image-max-width: 300px;
  --image-margin: 3rem;
  --font-family: "HK Grotesk";
  --font-family-header: "HK Grotesk";
}

/* Basic page style resets */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Import fonts */
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Regular.otf?v=1603136326027")
    format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.com/605e2a51-d45f-4d87-a285-9410ad350515%2FHKGrotesk-Bold.otf?v=1603136323437")
    format("opentype");
}

/* Our remix on glitch button */
.btn--remix {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 2.75rem;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.btn--remix img {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
.btn--remix:hover {
  background-color: #D0FFF1;
}

/* Navigation grid */
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
  padding: 1rem 0 0.75rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

.footer a:not(.btn--remix):link,
a:not(.btn--remix):visited {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-style: none;
}
.footer a:hover {
  background: var(--color-primary);
}

.footer .links {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.divider {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
/******************************************************************************
END Glitch hello-app default styles
******************************************************************************/

body {
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

/* Page structure */
.wrapper {
  min-height: var(--wrapper-height);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.title {
  color: #2800FF;
  font-family: HK Grotesk;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 105%;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Very light scaling for our illustration */
.illustration {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: var(--image-max-width);
  margin-top: var(--image-margin);
}

.button{
  font-size:35px;
  background-color:#ff4567;
  border-radius:50px;
  border:none;
  padding:20px 30px;
  color:#fff;
  margin:0px 10px;
}

.text{
  font-size:70px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
}

.text-retro{
  font-size:45px;
  font-family:'Courier New', monospace;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sumas!</title>
  
    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- the wrapper and content divs set margins and positioning -->
    <div id="score" style="text-align:center; padding:30px 0px;">
    <span>Good</span><span id="buenas"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>Wrong</span><span id="malas"></span> 
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span id="divsumando1" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">+</span>
    <span id="divsumando2" class="text"></span>
    <span class="text">=</span>
    </div>
      
      
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="btnopcion1" onclick="btn1()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion2" onclick="btn2()" class="button"></button>
    <button id="btnopcion3" onclick="btn3()" class="button"></button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="retro" class="text-retro">  
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="img" src="" height="200" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```